# VBA Excel copying the Visio current worksheet drawing and paste in Excel worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, visio

I would like to copy the stuff from Visio to excel, if that possible.

I found some hint here:

[Copying a visio page and pasting it in excel as an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56265048/copying-a-visio-page-and-pasting-it-in-excel-as-an-image)

and tried to use in my code:

```
 Sub Visio()
 vsoPage.CreateSelection(visSelTypeAll).Copy
 CIwb.Worksheets("Cables1").Paste
 End Sub
```

but I am getting error 424 - object required.
Debugger points the following line:

```
  vsoPage.CreateSelection(visSelTypeAll).Copy
```

[image]

How can I copy the current Visio worksheet to my current Excel sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Take a deep look at the answer you refer in your question: [Copying a visio page and pasting it in excel as an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56265048/copying-a-visio-page-and-pasting-it-in-excel-as-an-image)

There's a note:

> 'Assuming your **page object is named *vsoPage*** 'This embeds the visio
>   drawing

So, you have to use a name of Visio page, which you want to copy.
Another requirement is to use proper Excel workbook and worksheet. So, do not use dummy-copy of code. Instead of it, try to understand what it does and change it to your needs.

Note: code presented in original question is placed in Excel! If you want to run it from Visio, you need to:
1) create an instance of MS Excel
2) open existing Excel workbook or create new one
3) copy Visio page
4) close Excel workbook
5) close an instance of MS Excel application

Good luck!

Comment: I know, that the code in original question is in Excel. I want to run the code from Excel and take a snapshot of the current Visio drawing page.

Comment: So, use your: 1) Visio page name: `MojeObrazki`, but firstly you have to open Visio document and refer to this page, 2) workbook and worksheet name: `Workbooks("ShortFileName.xlsx").Worksheets("Arkusz1").Range("A1").Paste`

Comment: It looks like I still don't understand properly.
I created the Visio drawing sheet and changed its name to "MojeObrazki", next I superseded this name in the following code:
MojeObrazki.CreateSelection(visSelTypeAll).Copy
CIwb.Worksheets("Cables1").Paste

but I am getting error, that object is required.
It looks like the code in the explanation wasn't full enough. Firstly we must launch Visio using i.e this: 'Set objVisioDoc = objVisio.Documents.Open("C:\...\Visio file.vsd") and next do sth.

Comment: Exactly! You can not access an object which is not present ;) So, you need to create an instance of MS Visio appication, open the document, select page then to copy it into Excel sheet.